# Evaluating a claim based on confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm doing stats for the first time in 2 years, and I just want to make sure I'm approaching this problem correctly.

[image: problem]

With x and y meaning mean of sample 1 and sample 2

So I know that a confidence interval is computed by (x - y) +- t_crit*S_pooled*sqrt(1/n_x+1/n_y)

So I decided to work with 95% confidence:

So (525-515)+-t_crit*23*sqrt(2/48)

So I get 10+-t_crit*4.69.

And for my t_crit value I had 94 degrees of freedom (n_x+n_y-2) [I went the simple route] and since I wanted 95% confidence I found a table and got a t_crit value of 1.99.

So this gives me a confidence interval of [.66,19.34]

So I conclude that I am 95% confidence that the true difference between the two classes is between .66 and 19.34 points. Since this does not contain zero, I conclude that the parents' claims are justified.

Can I get a reality check on my approach to the problem, and if I'm correct?

For part b I just said if their standard deviations differ in such a way to include 0 in the confidence interval, it would change my conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Say the parents made an *a priori* prediction that each additional hour increased score by two points. Then the data shows that 5 extra hours resulted in 10 extra points on average. That is an astounding coincidence, unlikely if the the reasoning of the parents is totally invalid. I don't think the confidence interval containing zero or not should have anything to do with how we interpret the result.

However, if the claim was made by parents who had seen the data already then it is not justified. The CI is once again irrelevant since the "hypothesis" was generated and tested on the same data.

The question does not contain enough information. That's how I would answer, but probably not what the author of the question had in mind.